# The word order of “de ne pas avoir à”

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, prononciation, négation, ordre-des-mots

> Je suis [contente/content] de ne pas avoir à te trimballer !

I always thought that you have to place a verb or an auxiliary verb like `avoir` between `ne` and `pas`, so I wonder why this is not the case here. Is the `de ne pas avoir à` a set phrase, which means “to not have to”?

---

Also, I have a few questions about pronunciation:

1. Do you pronounce the phrase `pas avoir à` like it is a single word? [`pa-zavuwaa-ra`]
2. Do native French speakers often leave out the sound of the word `de` in this sentence in colloquial French?
3. If the speaker is a man, I should replace `contente` with `content`, correct? When pronouncing `content`, do you leave out the "`t`" sound from the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, usually you place the verb between "ne" and "pas", but that applies to conjugated verbs. When the verb is not conjugated, it goes after both particles, e.g. "*Ne pas manger*" or "*Ne pas ouvrir*". Your example is not an order, but the same principle applies. "*Ne pas avoir à*" is not really a set phrase, but more of a set construction, but it does indeed mean "to not have to".

Regarding your other questions, I think you mean to ask if we pronounce the liaisons between those words, as there's not really any concept of pronouncing a phrase like it's a single word. I think in this instance it's optional. I wouldn't pronounce the s, but some people would. I think it might be regional.

Native French speakers would not drop the "de", but would drop the "ne" while speaking. This applies to a lot of sentences. And you are right about your last question. "Content" is indeed pronounced without the final `t` sound.

Comment: Merci. I didn't know that when using the original form of a verb such as `ouvrir`, I should place the verb after `ne pas`. And... Oui, I wanted to ask about "liaisons". :) Now I understand that it is not common to liaise `pas` and `avoir`, but how about the liaison between `avoir` and `à`? Do you pronounce them like `avoirà`?

Comment: And yes, I have noticed that French speakers tend to drop `ne` in colloquial speech. Would you drop `ne` in this sentence: "Je suis contente de pas avoir à te trimballer !"?

Comment: *Infinitive* form, not *original* form. Words like these help a lot with googling things :)

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre The `r` is not actually a liaison because you would pronounce the R no matter what, so it will bleed in the next word but it's nothing special. On the other hand, if you say "pas" on its own, you don't pronounce the `s`. Pronouncing a letter that is not usually pronounced because of the following word is liaison. You may want to have a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)).

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre And yes, that is how I would say it; dropping the "ne" if I just spoke the sentence. I might actually say something like "J'suis contente de pas avoir à t'trimballer". A lot of final E's are shifted into [schwas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) in French and might end up not pronounced (maybe particularly in Canada?).

Comment: Aussi [ceci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Schwa).